# not installing HWIOAuthBundle in symfony 2

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

When I try to install HWIOAuthBundle I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'hwi\oauthbundle\HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\prjectName\app\AppKernel.php on line 24
```

I have reference to [documentation](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/0.3/Resources/doc/1-setting_up_the_bundle.md), after running the composer , i do get hwi package downloded with path as C:\xampp\htdocs\prjectName\vendor\hwi\oauth-bundle\HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle  but when i include it in the AppKernel.php file as

24th line of AppKernel.php is:

```
new hwi\oauth-bundle\HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle(),
```

Comment: Check the case-sensitive, try `new HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the doccumentation says you should register this bundle to appKernel.php by adding

```
new HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle(),
```

instead of

```
new hwi\oauth-bundle\HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle(),
```

The path added to the `appKernel.php` is not the exact path of the bundle where it is added but the namespace + class name of the main bundle's class (which extends `Bundle`).